# NSManagedObjectContext's countForFetchRequest takes long time for larger object graph

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

For a CoreData based iOS application backed by sqlite database. Using `countForFetchRequest` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` takes about 1 min for an entity containing 1.5 million or more records.

Isn't there any way to get the count in a slightly less time ?

Though one opt for an in-memory counter based on insertion / deletion in that entity but this will not be helpful if one needs to copy that sqlite database from one iOS device to another via iTunes since the iOS application has file sharing enabled.
The sqlite database is stored in Documents directory.

Any idea on this ?

Comment: Note for readers 1 lakh is 100,000

Answer (score 3):

The speed of the count depends on your predicate.  The more complex the predicate the slower the count.

Please edit your question and show the predicate so that we can help you to improve its performance.

Secondarily, have you run this code through instruments to **verify** that it is the count that is slow?  You may end up being surprised that some other event is occurring that is the actual slow part.

Comment: though Im sure you are right that is the predicate too complex

Comment: There is no predicate involved in the counting since I am using MagicalRecord's  + (NSUInteger) countOfEntities method which is used on NSManagedObject subclass. As I need to get the count of all records so no predicate in scene here. Also no other processing going on as the counting process being the first process that starts when very first screen comes in place. I am also sure that MagicalRecord has completed its setup before going for count.

Comment: Then I cannot help you as I do not work with Magical Record.  However I did not see the word "Instruments" in there so I would suggest, again, to run Instruments and verify what is slow.  Count is fast and if there is no predicate it is very fast.  Something in MagicalRecord is causing an issue.

Comment: countOfEntites is simply a wrapper around the countForFetchRequest:error: method on NSManagedObjectContext. More than likely your cause for slowness is elsewhere as counts are fairly quick. Have you measured your Core Data performance with Instruments or even look at the output from enabling Core Data logging?

Comment: enabling core data logging one can see that the underlying query fired is select count(distinct(Z_Pk)) from entityName. Obviously there will be a difference in time taken when one includes a distinct keyword in query then what if going without "distinct". plz correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Isn't there a way to enforce a count of records in core data that will avoid the distinct usage ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not use MagicalRecord but it definitely appears that it is doing something to the `-count...` call.  A direct call to Core Data's `-count...` will reveal more since that distinct should not be in there.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved that long time taking count issue by

```
NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [NSManagedObjectContext context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"MyEntityID"]];
    [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];

    NSError *err;
    count = [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
```

Here 'MyEntityID' is marked as index column. Using above method takes about 6 seconds whereas earlier it is about 62 seconds for that 1500000

Comment: Reading your answer it seems you did what I just suggested on the other thread :)